# What is the meaning of this future perfect sentence?

Tags: time, future-perfect

Sentence: **By The end of thirty years, I will have travelled to Europe?**

After 30 years, What is the exact location of me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example sentence's **by the end of thirty years** is not quite idiomatic, and so it's difficult to say what the speaker intends.

If you plan to make a trip to Europe thirty years from now, when you retire, for example:

> In thirty years time, I **will travel** to Europe.

If you know for certain that you will make a trip to Europe at some indefinite time in the future, but certainly not later than thirty years from now:

> In thirty years time, I **will have traveled** to Europe.

**Will have traveled** looks back upon the past from a point in time projected into the future.  It is "future hindsight".

With the simple future, we can say that in thirty years time you will be in Europe. With the future perfect, however, we do not know when you are going to take the trip. All that we know is that it will  take place at some point in the next three decades. It could be next year, or ten years from now. It might not happen until year 29.

Answer (score 1):

The example sentence does not say where you will be "after 30 years".  It says that (sometime during the thirty years) you plan to travel to Europe, but it does not specify the time more precisely than that.  It implies that you are not in Europe now.  It does not imply whether you will be in or out of Europe at the end of the thirty years, nor does it imply whether you will be alive or dead at the end of the thirty years.

Comment: Basically, the only thing implied by the sentence about your location is that when you say the sentence you are not in Europe and that sometime during the next 30 years you will be (at least momentarily) in Europe.